# Distinguishing two frieze patterns with symmetry group cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

Among the seven frieze patterns, there are two, whose symmetry group is infinite cyclic.

For example, one may see first two in picture below (Ref: Gallian's book on algebra, Chapter on Frieze Groups and Crystallographic Groups) or in the [link here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol1/architecture/Math/seven.html).

The two frieze patterns with cyclic symmetry group are obtained as follows:

(1) Walk only by left foot in a straight line; then the pattern of foot-print is a frieze pattern.

(2) Walk as usual in a straight line; then the pattern of left-right foot prints is a frieze patterns.

**Question:** What is correct geometric way to distinguish these patterns? These patters are generated by repeated application of generator of symmetry group to a single foot-print (in positive and negative directions).
For first one, it is just translation. For the second pattern, we repeatedly apply glide reflection.

Since, these patterns are one dimensional, so I was unable to compare translation and glide-reflection because they are different as motions in "2-dimensional plane" (orientation preserving-reversing).

[image]

Comment: It's not quite right to assume that borders are one-dimensional. They don't fit in a straight line, they at least need a lane. These seven patterns have a symmetry group, in which the translation group is a cyclic group.

Comment: Then, among the first two, they have same symmetry group; how do we distinguish them?

Comment: They are distinguished by geometry but not by algebra. The first group consists only of translations, and the subgroup of translations is of index 2 in the second group.

Comment: I think, the groups can be distinguished "by actions": the translations keep each parallel line in the one-dimensional pattern invariant; whereas, the glide-reflection keeps only one line invariant - the line along which gliding (reflection) is done.